# ¿Cómo puedo poner el texto al lado del div?

Tags: html, css, web

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<div class="plate">
    <p class="text-plate">MATRÍCULA</p>
    <div class="front-plate">
        <p class="front-text">FRONTAL</p>
        <p class="front-lock">FIJADA</p>
        <div class="front-panel">8457A513</div>
    </div>
    <div class="rear-plate">
        <p class="rear-text">TRASERA</p>
        <p class="rear-lock">FIJADA</p>
        <div class="rear-panel">8457A513</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Este es mi código, me gustaría colocar el texto "frontal" y "fijada" al lado de su div correspondiente, ¿alguien sabe como puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Saludos @MateoCode, no olvides adjuntar el código html y css que tienes para poder ayudarte, todas las preguntas deben ir acompañadas por el código mínimo verificable por favor revisa [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). ;)

Comment: Buenas mateo. Anteriormente se te dijo, pon el CODIGO junto a lo que necesitas, por que no somos adivinos y nadie te hará las cosas completamente.

Comment: Investiga un poco sobre display:flex de css y el cásico "float" es así como se hace.

Comment: Vale gracias, voy a ver que tal

Comment: Con el tipico "float: right" no cambia nada, voy a ver si con flexbox puedo hacerlo

Answer (score 2):

Yo usaría `Flexbox` para poder hacerlo mas rápido te muestro el código que implemente y te explico adentro de el para que sirven, por otro lado si te interesa aprender mas sobre `Flexbox` te dejo este [Link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
.plate {
    width: 300px;
}
.plate-container {
    display: flex; /*Convertimos al menú en flexbox*/
    justify-content: space-between; /*Con esto le indicamos que margine todos los items que se encuentra adentro hacia la derecha e izquierda*/
    align-items: center; /*con esto alineamos de manera vertical*/
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="plate">
        <p class="text-plate">MATRÍCULA</p>
        <div class="plate-container">
            <div class="front-plate-text">
                <p class="front-text">FRONTAL</p>
                <p class="front-lock">FIJADA</p>
            </div>
            <div class="front-panel">8457A513</div>
        </div>
        <div class="plate-container">
            <div class="front-plate-text">
                <p class="front-text">TRASERA</p>
                <p class="front-lock">FIJADA</p>
            </div>
            <div class="rear-panel">8457A513</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Por otro lado, no es necesario tener asignado varias clases diferente para items que van a hacer la misma función, una forma de ahorrar código es usando la misma clases para aquellas cosas que ya sabes que van a tener la misma función, un ejemplo tuyo Tenes: `.front-plate` y `.rear-plate` esas dos clases tiene como objetivo tener a sus hijos marginados a la derecha e izquierda por lo tanto para ahorra código solo ponele la misma class en el ejemplo mío le puse `.plate-container`.

Espero ayudarte con esto, cualquier cosa me comentas, Suerte!

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias, es justo lo que estaba buscando!